Why does my IP changed with SNMP Communication when response Broadcast on Android using SNMP4J
I am developing an SNMP-based application for Android, where both the agent (device-side) and the management station (mobile phone) are running on the Android platform, utilizing the SNMP4J library.
Due to permission constraints on the agent side, I am using port 1610 instead of the standard SNMP port 161. I have set up iptables to redirect traffic from port 161 to 1610 using the following command:

iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i wlan0 -p udp --dport 161 -j REDIRECT --to-port 1610


Now, I am facing an issue while discovering devices on the local network. Here's the setup:
Device IP: 192.168.0.100
Phone IP: 192.168.0.150

The logic for discovering devices on the mobile phone is as follows:

Send a broadcast using a socket, including the OID of the device-side agent, using SNMP to address 192.168.0.255.

   Source: 192.168.0.150:33429 (33429 is not a fixed port)
   Target: 192.168.0.255:161


The agent on the device receives the broadcast request, adds the data for each OID, and sends the response back using an SNMP4J function called returnResponsePdu.

   Source: 192.168.0.255:161
   Target: 192.168.0.150:33429

The problem is that when the SNMP agent on Android replies to the broadcast data, the source IP changes from 100 to 255 in the last octet.
However, when I directly send a request from the phone to the device using SNMP4J and specifying the IP, the response IP is correct:

Phone => Device

   Source: 192.168.0.150:33429
   Target: 192.168.0.100:161


Device response => Phone

   Source: 192.168.0.100:161
   Target: 192.168.0.150:33429

